# get members count with family detail and hof detail mysql

Tags: mysql, tree, parent

```
persons table
-----------------
id name fatherid motherid famid
---------------------
 1 ras  lovely   beautiful 5    
 2 abc  def      ghi       5    
 3 xyz  abc      aay       4

family table
----------------
famid hof ( id from persons)
------------------------
    4 3
    5 2
```

output required

```
-------------------
membercount(id with famid) hof_name hof_id(id from person) famid
-------------------
                         2 abc      2                      5
                         1 xyz      3                      4
```

please help me to get the correct query

Comment: Strange 'ids'!!

Comment: Why do you choose 'abc' instead of 'ras'?

Comment: Because he is head of family in his family